# API callback response

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I'm using an API to send sms in my codeigniter project. After sending, it will return a response array in the form of json to a callback url in my project. And i need to update this response in my database. Here is my code :

the response array will be similar as follows :

`{"req_id":"809ff62f-74a9-45a5-9cb5-5e60763289af","status":"0" ,"comment":"OK"}`

my callback url redirects to following function in my controller

```
public function templateCallback() {

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
    $json = urldecode($json);
    $obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);  
    $reqID = $obj->req_id;
    $status = $obj->status;
    print_r($obj);
    $this->db->where('TemplateRequestID', $reqID);
    $this->db->set('TemplateApproved', $status);
    $this->db->update('templatemaster_tbl');

}
```

But its never get updated. What is wrong in my code ? I'm not good in json. So i'm not sure is this the correct way to fetch and decode json array in php. Someone please help me.

To test this i have created a view in my project and send this same array through an ajax function like :

```
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url()?>';
    $('#test').click(function() { 
        var val = $('#testvalue').text();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: base_url + 'API/templateCallback',

            data: {
                val
            },
            success: function (response) { console.log(response);


            }
        });
    });
```

and try to print both `$json` and `$obj` in controller function.

`$json` displays a string like : `val=%7B%22req_id%22%3A%228b3eef97-330a-4271-8450-0676fbac8885%22%2C%22status%22%3A%220%22%2C%22comment%22%3A%22OK%22%7D`

and `$obj` displays nothing

Comment: what is the value of `print_r($obj);`?

Comment: Maybe try to `urldecode($json);` first

Comment: what about `print_r($json);`?

Comment: @Mark i used `urldecode($json)` it displays `val={"req_id":"8b3eef97-330a-4271-8450-0676fbac8885","status":"0","comment":"OK"}`. this is actually used to test my code. i expect a response without `val=` . So i think it will work.

Comment: Instead of `$json = file_get_contents('php://input')`, simply try `$data = $_POST`. jQuery will sort your json object out and post it as ordinary post-data by default. No need to mess around with the decoding etc by hand.

Comment: _A note about json_decode():_ If you're passing `true` as a second argument, that function will return an _array_ and not an object.

Comment: @Magnus the ajax function above is just used for testing. Actually the json is a API response. So I cannot tell it is a post variable or get variable.

Comment: An API should be very explicit about the HTTP Method. If the endpoint is for setting data, use POST, getting data, use GET, updating data, use PUT and deleting data, use DELETE. Don't have a multipurpose endpoint that accepts what ever and still does the same thing.

Comment: @all Thanks a lot. I solved my issue . I used `urldecode($json)` and there is one more mistake, that is , i used to set `TRUE` in json_deocde() and fetch the value in object method. So I changed `$obj->req_id` and `$obj->status` to `$obj['req_id']` and `$obj['status']` respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `$json` contains encoded value (`%7B%22req_id%22%3A%228b3eef97-330a-4271-8450-0676fbac8885%22%2C%22status%22%3A%220%22%2C%22comment%22%3A%22OK%22%7D`) you should decode it first with [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

So proper code would be:

```
...
$jsonEncoded = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$json = urldecode($jsonEncoded);
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE); 
...
```

Comment: It will take time to get the response, and it will automatically get updated. So I cannot predict when it will updated in my db. so my question is , will my code work if the `$json` is `{"req_id":"809ff62f-74a9-45a5-9cb5-5e60763289af","status":"0" ,"comment":"OK"} `

Comment: @geeth I don't see any reason why it would be related to timing, maybe I misunderstood your question? If the content is already decoded, don't do urldecode again. If not, just do and continue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved my issue . I used urldecode($json) and there is one more mistake, that is , i used to set TRUE in json_deocde() and fetch the value in object method. So I changed $obj->req_id and $obj->status to $obj['req_id'] and $obj['status'] respectively